# Design help using css

Tags: css

I need to achieve a nice  2 column layout as shown in [image]

So far i could get only: https://jsfiddle.net/8qskxqfh/

```
code in fiddle link
```

Could you please suggest me on improving this design.

```css
.myRatingBoxRed {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: red;
}

.myRatingBoxYellow {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.myRatingBoxGreen {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: green;
}

.myResourceViewBody {
  width: 960px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.myResourceViewBody.myResourceSideBar {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 800px;
  color: #fff;
}

.myResourceViewInfo {
  background: #fff;
  padding-left: 300px;
}

.myResourceViewInfo .section-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #2d7788;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.myResourceViewInfo .attributes-section .item {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.h2.myResourceTitle {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #9A3324 none repeat scroll 0px 0px;
  width: 66%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  padding-top: inherit;
  margin-top: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.myResourceViewBody ul {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: 300px;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="myResourceHeader">
  <h2 class="header-title myResourceTitle">Test article 1</h2>
</div>
<div class="myResourceViewBody">
  <div class="myResourceSideBar">
    <div class="myImageBox"></div>
    <div class="myEvaluationArea">
      <div class="myRatingBoxRed"></div>
      <div class="myRatingBoxYellow"></div>
      <div class="myRatingBoxGreen"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="myResourceViewInfo">
    <h2 class="myViewInfo section-title"><i class="fa icon-info-sign"></i>Description</h2>
    <ul>

      <li>demo 1</li>
      <li>demo 2</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="myResourceViewFooter"></div>
```

Comment: One advice: try to check bootstrap how `.row` and `.col-xxxx` classes works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check example below:

```css
.row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.row:after {
  clear: both;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.width-70 {
  width: 70%;
}

.width-30 {
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col width-30">
  col1
  </div>
  <div class="col width-70">
  col2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using col-spans inside row

something like this

```
<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-6">
//first column
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
// second column
</div>
</div>
```

refer to bootstrap classes for more details and how to make it responsive also.